# How to setup a bridge as an AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am trying to setup a test environment on my Amazon cloud for a proxy component.

The proxy component is an ec2 instance that all of network traffic pass through it.

```
client
 _____
|_____| ------|                    
              |
client        |         proxy
 _____        |        _______
|_____| ------| ----> |_______| -----> Internet
              | 
client        |
 _____        |
|_____| ------|
```

I created a VPC but I can't understand how can I "connect" each client to pass its traffic to the proxy.

## EDIT

The way our proxy works is by using a bridge interface (br0) that transfer the network data between eth0 to eth1 and back.

```
EC2-instance  |
 _____        |
|_____| ------|                    
              |          proxy (bridge)
EC2-instance  |         (Also ec2-user)
 _____        |        __________________        ________________
|_____| ------|       |__________________| ---->|Internet Gateway|---> Internet
              |------>|        br0       |       
EC2-instance  |
 _____        |
|_____| ------|
```

Does this kind of network topology configuration is also configurable in AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understand for your question, if you can provide detail or need some adjusts, let me know.

- assign all application clients to private subnets, don't assign
  internet gateway to its route table.
- create a NAT instance, you can use exist Amazon NAT AMI image to create
  it.

Community AMIs (amzn-ami-vpc-nat-pv-2015.03.0.x86_64-ebs - ami-XXXXXX)

- auto-sign public IP address or assign EIP(elastic IP) on this NAT instance
- Disabling Source/Destination Checks on this NAT instance.
- Updating the Main Route Table with this new NAT instance on the private subnets that you assign the IP addresses to your application clients.
- now all clients should be fine to access Internet directly via this NAT instance.

refer [Setting up the NAT Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#NATInstance)

Of course, you can [create a custom nat instance in AWS VPC](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/add-a-custom-nat-instance-in-aws-vpc/)

If you need something like squid proxy server, please give detail

Comment: I want the proxy server to use bridge_utils to bridge the traffic between the applications and the gateway but i can understand how to do it

Comment: @nivpenso what you want to do is impossible in AWS.  The network infrastructure is not a layer 2 network, it's a layer 3 network that emulates some of the capabilities of a layer 2 network. That design is what allows it to scale so massively, and efficiently.  Traffic cannot be bridged through an instance, it can only be routed, as this answer explains (depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish).

Comment: @nivpenso see also "A Day in the Life of a Billion Packets" mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21924252/1695906

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is there any other cloud interface, that you aware of, that allows this kind of bridging?

Comment: @nivpenso I am not aware of any, but most of my work is with AWS, which only supports routing through a NAT instance, as shown here.